# How to fix `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers`

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm using Python (Flask) with SQLAlchemy and Alembic.

I did a derpy thing and I accidentally defined an identically named backRef in two models.

e.g.

In `question.py`

```
    # Relationships
    question_option = db.relationship('QuestionOption', backref=db.backref('question', lazy=True))
```

In `question_options.py`

```
   # Relationships
    question = db.relationship('Question', backref=db.backref('question_options', lazy=True))
```

I removed the duplicate backRef from one of the models. Is this enough to fix the error or do I need to create a new revision and upgrade the head?

Answer (score 0):

Update: you can just delete the duplicate backRef from one of the models. You don't need to make a new Alembic revision because this isn't a schema change. I deleted the backref and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).